# Get Meta data in Azure Data Factory is not giving me my multiple excel files successfully

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to process multiple excel files in ADF to utilize them in a copy data activity to blob storage. Here is how my hierarchy is structured :

- My source is an excel sheet coming from SFTP server (linked service).
- File path: unnamed folder with multiple .xlsx files. Inside those files, the sheet name varies between sheet1 and table1.

I am trying to create get metadata to get all those files to pass them into a copy activity, but my metadata is never succeeding

Attached below is an elaboration about the problem:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems you get `Child Items` from file which leads to your error.  `Child Items` can only be used to get list of subfolders and files in the given folder. I'm not sure why you use Get Metadata activity? What do you want to get from that?

Comment: @SteveZhao but if I don't specify the field list it throws a `Field List in Metadata Can not be empty` warning. I am trying to get all the files in a list to pass it to for each activity and copy each of these files to blob storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to copy all excel files from SFTP to Blob Storage, there is no need to use Get Metadata activity.

Please try like this:

1.create binary format dataset
[image]

2.choose Wildcard file path when copy data
[image]

3.sink to your Blob Storage.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! 

but the reason I am using Get metadata Activity is that I want:
1.  To get my files copied to Blob Storage 
2. Get the `Last Modified Date` for all those files as well to update a table in my SQL DB.

Comment: If so, you need to select 'Last Modified' in field list of Get Metadata activity not 'Child Items'.(Make sure your Get Metadata activity's dataset is file not folder)